# Download big imap directory to maildir

Tags: email, imap, fetchmail

I search a solution to download (for archiving) a large mail directory via imap from a mail-server and stores all mails in a local maildir. I need a robust solution, which repeatedly tries if time-outs occur. So far I have tried using regular mail clients for this. Apparently the server restricts downloads in a way which confuses the clients I have tried so far in that they eventually give up and even loose mails. I am thinking of a tool like fetchmail, but the howtos I have seen are either a bit long or don't fit exactly my needs, such as http://llg.cubic.org/docs/imapbackup.html which describes download to mbox files. It remains unclear to me whether the maildir format is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/) which sounds like it should fit your purpose:

*isync is a command line application which synchronizes mailboxes; currently Maildir and IMAP4 mailboxes are supported. New messages, message deletions and flag changes can be propagated both ways. isync is suitable for use in IMAP-disconnected mode.*

Comment: Thanks. Together with https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync as basic configuration this seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two other options:

- [offlineimap](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap3/blob/master/offlineimap.conf) if you're using python3 make sure you get version 8.0.0 upward. Can also [migrate from one gmail account](https://www.pyrites.org.uk/post/migrate-gmail/) to another without losing labels
- [getmail6](https://getmail6.org/)